# Integrating distribution function

Tags: integration, probability-distributions

Say I have i.i.d data $X_1,\ldots,X_m\sim F$ and $Y_1,\ldots,X_n\sim F$, where $F$ is the distribution function.

How can I calculate the following integral? 
$$
W=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^s F(t)-F(t)F(s) \, d F(t) \, dF(s)
$$

**Edit** See solution below. As a side note for those interested, this was used to derive the asymptotic variance of the Mann-Whitney statistic using empirical process theory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $p=F(t)$ and $q=F(s)$. From the probability integral transform, since $X,Y$ are continuous random variables with continuous distribution $F$, then $F$ as a random variable is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$. By construction we have that $0\leq p\leq 1$ and $0\leq q\leq 1$. Note also that we changed the bounds of integration by applying $F(\cdot)$ to the original bounds of integration in the above equation.
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
W&=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{q} [p-pq]  dpdq\\
&=\int_{0}^{1} \left[\frac{1}{2}q^2-\frac{1}{2}q^3\right]  dpdq=\frac{1}{24}\\
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Answer (score 0):

Would it help you to make the change of variable f(s)= 1-F(s)? You could then write the integral as:
$$f(s)=1-F(s)$$
$$df(s)= -dF(s)$$
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{- \infty}^{s}dF(t) dF(s) [F(t)-F(t)F(s)] $$
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{- \infty}^{s}dF(t) dF(s) F(t)[1-F(s)]$$
$$-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}df(s) f(s) \int_{- \infty}^{s} dF(t) F(t)$$